# Use SAS to read data from SQL Server WITHOUT a sas/access license

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc

I have used SAS to read  data from SQL Server, and I am fairly certain I did it without having a sas/access license.

The code was along the lines of `LIBNAME mylib odbc  datasrc="DSNAME" user=xxx password=xxx`, where DSNAME was the name of an ODBC data source.

Is this possible or is it just likely that I did have the sas/access license available and didn't realise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an access license of some sort. You may have been using OleDD or ODBC vs a dedicated license. If you don't have SAS/Access license you can still simulate the product albeit nowhere as robust.

I wrote a solution to do this. The code is on my github repository. It isn't as fast, so you will have to work with that fact. See it here:
https://github.com/savian-net/SaviAccess

It is fully documented so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, you can write a VBScript which uses ODBC/OLEDB to connect to SQL Server, run the query, return the data back to an infile.